# Should I notify the user before opening another app from app?

Tags: iphone, notifications, uialertview

I have the following situation: There are three links in the footer of the table.

1. Facebook
2. Twitter
3. www.someaddress.com

When the user clicks(touchupinside) the first link I open the facebook app if exists otherwise safari.

When the user clicks the second one I open the twitter app if exists otherwise safari.

When the user clicks the tird link I open the safari.

The question is: should I display the alert view before opening external apps(facebook app, twitter app, Safari browser app)

```
Example of text in alertview: You are opening facebook app. Continue? Yes, No.
```

I want to know the good practice of doing this things, if it's necessary to do it or if it's annoying and bothers the user. What rules the app should comply with?

There is also another thing, iPhone 3 doesn't support multitasking and if accidentally the user clicks the link while scrolling the application will be closed and Safari opend and this can be considered as crash from the view of the user. Because app closes without notification.

Comment: this should be asked at http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: My opinion, don't bother the user, I don't see until now an app with such type of alerts. If the user click the link he expect to go there quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is not a correct behavior that could be OK in any situation.

I mean, if I am a user and I tap a button with facebook or twitter logo on it I expect to go there quickly, as  Mihai Panţiru pointed out.

On the contrary, if I tap a button with a typewriter on it and I go directly to "write a review" page, I could be disappointed.

In your situation, for example, you could show an alert to the user if your app runs on a device that doesn't support multitasking.

(BTW, I think that UIActionSheet is better than UIAlertView)

EDIT: You can check on which device your app is running:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)]) {
    // Multitasking is supported -> do not show any alert
} else {
    // Multitasking is NOT supported -> show an alert
}
```

Comment: I want that my application to work on iphone 3 and 4. Is it ok if the same app will be with alertview for iphone 3 and without for iphone 4? What actually means different design and different user experience for different devices. Or the app should be identical for all the devices? I didn't find these answers in App Store Guidlince.

Comment: I mean you can check on which device your app is running and change its behavior. Take a look at my EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on for what purpose you are opening other app ,there is no compulsion in it.

If you are opening the the other app for log in purpose (Facebook,twitter etc.) then there is no need to show the alert to the user as it is the default and new way of authentication by Facebook,twitter etc.User will have to obviously leave the app for sign in.

But if you are opening the other app like safari or youtube for a web link to be shown in it ,Then in that condition you can show an alert,so that user can decide at that time if he want to leave the app or not for visiting that link.

Comment: Thanks for response, you want to say that it is allowed to open external apps like facebook and twitter without permision of the user?

Comment: yes,it is allowed to open external apps without permission,After sign in from facebook app it automatically opens our app again

Comment: if you want same behaviour of sign in for all devices,ios4 ,3,2 then you should show the sign in box in the app itself without going to external app as ios 3,2 doesn't provide multitasking background support